# Dynamic Annotation Text for R Gif Made with Magick

Tags: r, annotations, imagemagick, gif

I have some very basic code that reads files from a folder and makes a gif using the magick package. It produces the gif but I can't figure out how to make the annotation (image_annotate) dynamic. For example, instead of being "CAIDD_A" for each image I would like it t be "CAIDD_A_YYYY" with the year being updated for every image.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr) 
library(magick)
library(animation)

chennai_gif <- list.files(path="CAIDD_A",pattern = "*.tif", full.names = T) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>% 
  image_join() %>% 
  image_annotate("CAIDD", location =geometry_point(500,400), size = 42, color = "black") %>%
  image_animate(fps=2, loop=10) %>% 
  image_write("CAIDD_A.gif")
```

I tried to create a vector of characters for the annotations but got the following error:

```
Error in magick_image_annotate(image, text, gravity, location, degrees,  : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=43].
```

This code works, but it just annotates the entire string to the image...

```
Title =seq(2018,2060,by=1)
Title = toString(Title)

chennai_gif <- list.files(path="CAIDD_A",pattern = "*.tif", full.names = T) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>% 
  image_join() %>% 
  image_annotate(text=Title, location =geometry_point(500,400), size = 42, color = "black") %>%
  image_animate(fps=2, loop=10) %>% 
  image_write("CAIDD_A.gif")
```

Comment: Where do you get the `Year` from? Is this `Year` part of the image name?  According to the documentation of `image_annotate`: `text` can be  
character vector of length equal to 'image' or length 1

Comment: @yifyan yes the year is part of the file name. I thought there should be a way to make the annotation a vector but when I tried this it didn't work. Do you have an example?

Answer (score -1):

How about something like using `str_c()` from the `stringr` package? (or alternatively `paste0()` with base R.) For example:

```r
library(stringr)
year <- str_extract(Sys.Date(), "\\d{4}")

chennai_gif <- list.files(path="CAIDD_A",pattern = "*.tif", full.names = T) %>% 
  map(image_read) %>% 
  image_join() %>% 
  image_annotate("CAIDD", location =geometry_point(500,400), size = 42, color = "black") %>%
  image_animate(fps=2, loop=10) %>% 
  image_write(str_c("CAIDD_A.gif", year))
```

Comment: I need the years associated with the file names (43 in total) to show up on each image of the gif.